# How to target div within a modal box with CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I target just this image to apply css styling to it?

```
<img class="images BadgeImgOutline responsive-image" src="http://kudosoo.com/GBadges/badge8.jpg" style="width: 122px; height: 122px;">
```

I've tried several selector combinations in CSS, but cannot seem to target it correctly.
(for example img.images #modal .img)

The image displayed within the badgeselect div

```
<div id="modal" class="login-form">
                    <div id="heading">

                    </div>          

                        <div id="badgeselect">
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img.images.BadgeImgOutline.responsive-image{
/* styles */
}
```

Although it seems

```
img.BadgeImgOutline{
/* styles */
}
```

Would suffice.

[**I would also suggest you read up on CSS  selectors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

The selector you use depends on the level of specificity required, i.e. if you wish to select only that image, what can you reference to only identify it, and nothing else (for increased efficiency) - the main way of doing so would be to assign it an `id` attribute and then use it as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

`#modal img.images.BadImgOutline.response-image { .... }` should do the trick, unless you've got other images with the exact same CSS class inside your modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to close `<img>` tag like this `<img />` so it will be like this

```
<img class="images BadgeImgOutline responsive-image" src="http://kudosoo.com/GBadges/badge8.jpg" style="width: 122px; height: 122px;" />
```

then you can target it using **CSS** like this:

```
img.images.BadgeImgOutline.responsive-image{
    /* Some CSS code */
}
```

or

```
#modal img{
    /* Some CSS code */
}
```

or both of them together

```
#modal img.images.BadgeImgOutline.responsive-image{
    /* Some CSS code */
}
```

Hope this will help you ..